# How to forEach data without concat all then dynamic ? Javascript , map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to dynamically display the results. The problem is that I just concat the first and second element in the object and I have to do it through some loop or dynamically.

Code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In the stackblitz, you will see the problem written.

```
   this.allFilters.map(filerVal => {
     if (Array.isArray(filerVal.value)) 
       filerVal.value = `${filerVal.value[0]?.value} : ${(filerVal.value[1]?.value ? filerVal.value[1]?.value : '')}`
       return filerVal;
      });
```

This is problem:

```
 filerVal.value = `${filerVal.value[0]?.value} : ${(filerVal.value[1]?.value ? filerVal.value[1]?.value : '')}`
```

I am concat string first and second element but in my array have four element... How to show all data.

Expected result will be:

> 1 : 2 : 3 : 4
>
> 15
>
> 1 : 2 : 3 : 4

Right now is :

> 1 : 2 ( missing 3 and 4 )
>
> 15
>
> 1 : 2 ( missing 3 and 4 )

Comment: `.map()` is used to transform every item in an array. As such, it must always return a value. If you're not interested in transfirming every item in an array, don't use `.map()`. You probably need `.forEach()` or better still, a `for` loop (better because it can be interrupted)

Comment: When I used forEach it does the same. What matters to me is how to format the string I merged, does it need a loop or what?

Comment: The main problem is you're overwriting `filterVale.value` with this line `filerVal.value = ${filerVal.value[0]?.value} : ${(filerVal.value[1]?.value ? filerVal.value[1]?.value` In the first pass, `filerVal.value` is no longer an array of items and becomes `'1 : 2'` then `filerVal.value.value` no longer exists.

Comment: @MichaelHoobler yes that is true. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  recieveMessage(data) {
    this.allFilters.push(Array.isArray(data.value) ?
          data.value.map(obj => obj.value).join(":")
          : data.value)
  }
```

and

```
  <span *ngFor="let filter of allFilters">
                 {{ filter }} 
 </span>
```

This gives :

```
1:2:3
15
1:2:3:4
```

I understand that's the output you expect?

Forked Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expample-ykruwd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I think they want whitespace so " : ", right?

Comment: this is okay but for me this is different... I have two object in my this.allfilters.. I don;t know how. Stackblitz is only demonstration how looks but in my code this work different ...don't know how ?

Comment: I have forked your Stackblitz and added the link to it in my answer

Comment: Stackblitz is same. In my code i got two object here like a 0: {name: "one", value: 2}
1: 2

Second object is 1: 2

Comment: Ah that's right sorry, I forked your Stackblitz but it didn't keep my changes. I have updated it, have a look

Comment: Sorry friend my mistake. Your code work perfect. Vote up. But one more thinks. Can I set in this.allFilters object with { name: ''name" : value : 2 } because i need remove this by name ...

Comment: Ok no problem just , Can I set in this.allFilters object with { name: ''name" : value : 2 } because i need remove this by name .

Comment: I don't understand what this means. What's the expected output? (Provide code instead of a description)